# Compact mATX case for NAS system with four 3.5" drives

Tags: case

I'm looking for a *compact* mATX case for a NAS system. One that I can stick in a corner somewhere and forget about (figuratively).

I have done some research into this, but all results I found that were less than 50 USD only had three or fewer drive bays. I found a few mATX cases with four 3.5" bays, but they were out of my budget range.

**Necessary Requirements:**

- Four bays for 3.5" HDDs
- Front Panel USB 2.0
- Less than $50 USD (lower is better, new not used)
- Approx. 3 inches of clearance for the CPU fan (~76mm)

**Optional, but would be nice:**

- Cube/LAN box style
- Dust Filters
- From Amazon.com

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the internal drives need to be 3.5"?  A 2x 3.5 bay using adapters to allow for 2x 2.5" drives per 3.5" bay would allow for 4x drives.

Comment: @NZKshatriya The internal drives do need to be 3.5". I say that because I plan on upgrading to larger drives soon and the price/GB of 2.5" drives >=3TB tends to be much higher than the price/GB of 3.5" drives >=3TB.

Comment: Along with my answer, you can also toss a 3.5" drive into a caddy in a 5.25" bays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find a cube style but the following did come across as a good option.

[SilverStone PS08B @ Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811163223&ignorebbr=1) 39.99

[SilverStone PS08B @ Amazon(prime eligible)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A1ZU1I0) 39.99

Just posted the Newegg link along with the Amazon link, due to the fact that Newegg is much better with item specifications....and power searches...than Amazon is.

Just a few specs on the case:
2 x USB 3.0 / Audio Front Ports

Side Air duct

2 External 5.25" Drive Bays

4 Internal 3.5" Drive Bays